# The client to invoke an error is as follows:org.xml.sax.SAXException: SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element, which is NOT expected

Tags: java, hibernate, apache-axis

Who can help me, I was going to collapse, so thank you
The client to invoke an error is as follows，error:
The client to invoke an error is as follows，error:

```
- Exception:
org.xml.sax.SAXException: SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element, which is NOT expected, in something it was trying to deserialize.
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.SimpleDeserializer.onStartChild(SimpleDeserializer.java:145)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.startElement(DeserializationContext.java:1035)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SAX2EventRecorder.replay(SAX2EventRecorder.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement.publishToHandler(MessageElement.java:1141)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.deserialize(RPCElement.java:236)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.getParams(RPCElement.java:384)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2467)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at com.hxc.soap.HxcNewsServiceSoap12BindingStub.find(HxcNewsServiceSoap12BindingStub.java:254)
    at com.hxc.soap.Test.main(Test.java:11)
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: org.xml.sax.SAXException: SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element, which is NOT expected, in something it was trying to deserialize.
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:org.xml.sax.SAXException: SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element, which is NOT expected, in something it was trying to deserialize.
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.SimpleDeserializer.onStartChild(SimpleDeserializer.java:145)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.startElement(DeserializationContext.java:1035)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SAX2EventRecorder.replay(SAX2EventRecorder.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement.publishToHandler(MessageElement.java:1141)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.deserialize(RPCElement.java:236)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.getParams(RPCElement.java:384)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2467)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at com.hxc.soap.HxcNewsServiceSoap12BindingStub.find(HxcNewsServiceSoap12BindingStub.java:254)
    at com.hxc.soap.Test.main(Test.java:11)

    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:geduo_pc

org.xml.sax.SAXException: SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element, which is NOT expected, in something it was trying to deserialize.
    at org.apache.axis.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:101)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2470)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at com.hxc.soap.HxcNewsServiceSoap12BindingStub.find(HxcNewsServiceSoap12BindingStub.java:254)
    at com.hxc.soap.Test.main(Test.java:11)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element, which is NOT expected, in something it was trying to deserialize.
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.SimpleDeserializer.onStartChild(SimpleDeserializer.java:145)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.startElement(DeserializationContext.java:1035)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SAX2EventRecorder.replay(SAX2EventRecorder.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement.publishToHandler(MessageElement.java:1141)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.deserialize(RPCElement.java:236)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.getParams(RPCElement.java:384)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2467)
    ... 4 more
```

server code:(axis2+hibernate+spring)

```
public class HxcNewsService implements IHxcNewsService {    
    private IDao dao;   
    public void setDao(IDao dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }
    public HxcNews find(int id){
        return (HxcNews) dao.find("com.ews.bean.HxcNews",id);
    }
}

public class Dao<T> extends HibernateDaoSupport implements IDao<T> {

    public T find(String str,int id) {

        try {
            T t = (T) getHibernateTemplate().get(str, id);
            return t;
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {         
            throw re;
        }

    }
```

## }

client code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            HxcNewsServicePortType hxcNewsServicePortType = new HxcNewsServiceLocator().getHxcNewsServiceHttpSoap12Endpoint();
            HxcNews news = hxcNewsServicePortType.find(1);
            System.out.println(news.getTitle());                    
        } catch (ServiceException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: is it not problem that result from dao contains xml/html elements that are not "escaped" ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is due to the xml output being returned from `find()` method of your `HcxNewsService` class. Some XML IS successfully returned, and it is not sufficiently well formed for it to deserialize (*re construct an object out of it*).

As mentioned in the stack trace...
"`encountered a child element, which is NOT expected, in something it was trying to deserialize`" (SAXParser did not understand the XML implies that xml is not correctly formed).

Possible debugging options are try to get the xml tied object directly from DAO... Log it...

```
public class Dao<T> extends HibernateDaoSupport implements IDao<T> {

    public T find(String str,int id) {

        try {
            T t = (T) getHibernateTemplate().get(str, id);
            System.out.println.t.toString()); // OR...
            LOGGER.info(t.toString());
            return t;
        } cach (RuntimeException re) {         
            throw re;
        }

    }
}
```

If this fails, do the same approach with calling code in the server...

```
public class HxcNewsService implements IHxcNewsService {    
    private IDao dao;   
    public void setDao(IDao dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }
    public HxcNews find(int id){
        // before returning, see what is database returning...
        LOGGER.log(dao.find("com.ews.bean.HxcNews",id));
        return (HxcNews) dao.find("com.ews.bean.HxcNews",id);
    }
}
```

Let us know how you solved it finally.